# How to insert a value in a column's specific ranging rows, according to a condition. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a dataframe that has a column named **season** (newly created, np.nan filled), another column is **match_id**, it's values are like: match 1 has **match_id** *1*, match 2 has **match_id** *2*, ... , match n has **match_id** *n*. It's **cricket** (close to baseball) dataset so it's ball by ball. 1 match has **20+20 overs** max (Each over has 6 balls). So **match_id** *1* is approx from index 0 to 240. Then **match_id** *2* is approx from index 241 to 480. Data is ball by ball (1 row for 1 ball)/match by match(approx 240 rows for 1 match)/ Season by Season (approx 14160 rows for 1 season).

My condition is that if **match_id** is from *1* to *59*, place *2017* in those **season** column rows.

In my dataset **match_id** and other columns pre existed. I created np.nan column **season**, now I want to fill it.

my data looks like,

```
In[]: df_raw.head(6)
out[]:
    season  match_id    inning  batting_team         bowling_team                  over ball
0   NaN     1           1       Sunrisers Hyderabad  Royal Challengers Bangalore   1    1
1   NaN     1           1       Sunrisers Hyderabad  Royal Challengers Bangalore   1    2
2   NaN     1           1       Sunrisers Hyderabad  Royal Challengers Bangalore   1    3
3   NaN     1           1       Sunrisers Hyderabad  Royal Challengers Bangalore   1    4
4   NaN     1           1       Sunrisers Hyderabad  Royal Challengers Bangalore   1    5
5   NaN     1           1       Sunrisers Hyderabad  Royal Challengers Bangalore   1    6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively use `loc` function:

```
df.loc[(df['match_id']<=59) & (df['match_id']>=1), 'season'] = 2017
```

Note that since `season` column contains NaNs it will be stored as floating point numbers. When you have finished filling in the `season` values you can convert the values to integers

```
df['season'] = df['season'].astype('int')
```

Answer (score 3):

I split the process into two steps but you can just as well merge the two in to one line.

First check if the match_id is in the specified range, then overwrite with the desired value based on the condition.

```
df['season'] = df['match_id'].isin(range(1,60)
df['season'] = df['season'].apply(lambda x: 2017 if x else np.nan)
```